# Is there a way to combine two gvim windows into one window with multiple tabs?

Tags: vim

I will often open one file in gvim, go back to the terminal, and open another file in another directory in a new instance of gvim. I wanted to know if there was an easy way to combine these two instances of gvim into one window with each file in a separate tab, or if there was an easy way to open a second file in the first gvim window. I don't want to have to copy the path of the second file to use in the first gvim window, and I don't want to do file searching in the first gvim window.

Answer (score 2):

For moving multiple files / tab pages to the other GVIM instance, I would write a *session file*, quit that Vim instance, and then open the saved session in the other one. Cp. `:help session-file`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge the two windows but you can look at the title bar of the target GVim window and use its session name in the source window:

```
:!gvim --servername VIM2 %
```

See `:help clientserver`.

---

Note that Vim's tab pages are not and can't be file proxies.

Answer (score 1):

The workflow that you describe would be better suited for vim in the terminal then you would not have to worry about managing multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

Merging two separate windows is not possible. Using [Ctrl-p](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) plugin will lessen the burden of typing the file path as you don't want that.

Just by typing `<ctrl-p>` followed by the few/all characters of the files/directory and hitting `<ctrl-t>` to open in tab view once you got the desired file.